# How to edit Excel (xlsx and xlsm) in python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am very new to Python and this is my first project in python.

What I am doing is...
1. Retrieved the data from Sql server
2. Put the data in predefined excel template (specific worksheet).
3. If is there any data in this sheet then it should be replaced and only column name should remain in the sheet.
3. Another sheet in excel template contains a Pivot representation of data from step 2.
4. I need to refresh this pivot with new data from sheet1.
5. no of row in sheet1 can be changed depends on data from database.

I am fine with Step1 but unable oto perform excel operations.

I tried openpyxl but not able to much understand of it.
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb2 = load_workbook('CnA_Rec.xlsx')
print (wb2.sheetnames)

rawsheet = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('RawData')

print (rawsheet.cell_range)
```

Error with above code:

```
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'cell_range'
```

I can access individual cell but not range.
I need to select current range and replace it will new data.

ref link: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.html

Can any one point me to some online example for the same or any sample code for this.

Comment: Does this help? https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Comment: xlsxwriter works with new files only. It doesn't support editing existing one. Let me know if I am wrong with my understanding...

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. What about the other modules? Did you test them?

Comment: I tried openpyxl. It seems promising but unable to find any example for this.

Comment: Do you have to use Python? Autoit is able to your tasks very easily.

Comment: Yes... Python it is. Company-wise decision.

Comment: Your question is far too broad and contains no actual code. What you want to do is possible but you will have to do quite a bit of work yourself.

Comment: I have done some code and now updated question with my code. I need help with Cell Range.
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.html
This link tell us the same but I am unable to use these functions as getting below error:
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'cell_range'

Comment: I have updated question with this same info.

Answer (score 2):

So, then let go for it with openpyxl. Where is your problem? This is a very basic start. We can change this script during the process.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('hello_world.xlsx')
# do magic with openpyxl here and save
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
ws.cell(row=1, column=3).value = 'Hello'   # example
ws.cell(row=2, column=3).value = 'World'   # example

for i in range(2,20):
    ws.cell(row=i,column=1).value = 'Row:' + str(i)

data = [ws.cell(row=i,column=1).value for i in range(1,11)]
print(data)

wb.save('hello_world.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks... I am able to access/update individual cell. I am facing issue with cell Range. Updated question with my code also.